# Please Help a javascript to cut parts of links?

Tags: javascript

If I put this link

> `http://www.google.co.in/search?nomo=1&q=Quantum+physics+india&client=ms-opera-mini&channel=new&hl=en&`

in textarea and submit, it should give me a clean link in another textarea after page loads, like this:

> `http://www.google.com/search?q=Quantum+physics+india`

How will be the javascript for this ?

Comment: How do you define "clean link"? Remove every parameter except `q`? And  what exactly are you having problems with? Processing the URL? Listening to the event that changes the value of the textarea? Something else?

Comment: Thats one hell of a vague question to be upvoted o.O

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `indexOf()` and `substr()` you can extract the `q=` parameter and append it to the new link. This also trims off any additional parameters after the `q=` (if any).

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SvnbH/3/)**

```
function convertLink(input)
{
    var newLink = "http://www.google.com/search?";

    var temp =  input.substr(input.indexOf('q='));
    var ampPos = temp.indexOf('&');

    if(ampPos > -1)
    {
        temp = temp.substr(0, ampPos);
    }

    return newLink + temp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a regex match.  something like q=/([A-Za-z]*\+?)*/

that should extract the part you want, and you can then append it to your base-url.

as for how to code it, I believe that doing is the best way to learn, but you might start [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)

Comment: This regex will fail, better user a negated character class `[^&]*`

Answer (score 0):

if "nomo=1&q=Quantum+physics+india&client=ms-opera-mini&channel=new&hl=en&" pattern is fixed 
Ex: (nomo=&q=&client=&channel=)

You will be able to get your answer using following script

```
var uri   = 'http://www.google.co.in/search?nomo=1&q=Quantum+physics+india&client=ms-opera-mini&channel=new&hl=en&';
var myarr = uri.split("?");

var url   = myarr[0];
//alert(myarr[0]);
var myarr2 = myarr[1].split("&");
//alert(myarr2[1]);

alert(url+'?'+myarr2[1]);
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is a generic function to parse any url:

> ```
> function parseQueryString(url) { 
>   var e, 
>       d = function (s) { 
>         return decodeURIComponent(s.replace(/\+/g, " ")); 
>       }, 
>       r = /([^&=]+)=?([^&]*)/g,
>       queryObject = {};
>
>   while (e = r.exec("url=" + url)) 
>   queryObject[d(e[1])] = d(e[2]);
>
>   console.dir(queryObject); 
>   return queryObject;
> }
> ```

When you call it for your url:
parseQueryString("http://www.google.co.in/search?nomo=1&q=Quantum+physics+india&client=ms-opera-mini&channel=new&hl=en&");

You get: Object

channel: "new"
lient: "ms-opera-mini"
hl: "en"
q: "Quantum physics india"
url: "http://www.google.co.in/search?nomo=1"

Comment: Please give Demo with jsFiddle if your code works..